# Using Google Books API to get ISBN from book title and author

Tags: json, google-apps-script, isbn, google-books-api

I have a Google form where people can submit books by author and book title. I would like to use this to retrieve the ISBN.

```
function atSubmitForm(e) {
  var formResponses = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponses.getItemResponses();
  var bookTitle = itemResponses[0].getResponse(); 
  var authorFirst = itemResponses[1].getResponse(); 
  var authorLast = itemResponses[2].getResponse(); 
 
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:\"" + bookTitle + "\" inauthor:\"" + authorFirst + " " + authorLast + "\"" + "&country=CA";
  var urlEncoded = encodeURI(url);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlEncoded);
  var result = JSON.parse(response);
  var items = result.items;
  
  var item = items[0].volumeInfo;
  for (var i = 0; i < item.industryIdentifiers.length; i++) {
    var id = item.industryIdentifiers[i];
    if (id.type === "ISBN_13") {
      var isbn = id.identifier;
    } 
  }
}
```

This isn't the whole function, obviously, but the ISBN is what's giving me problems.  It doesn't seem to be pulling the information I'm expecting. For example, the book *Children of Time* by Adrian Tchaikovsky will generate a urlEncoded = [https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:"Children+of+Time"+inauthor:"Adrian+Tchaikovsky"&country=CA](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:%22Children+of+Time%22+inauthor:%22Adrian+Tchaikovsky%22&country=CA) and it will return an isbn = 9780316452496. I don't know where this ISBN comes from but it isn't listed on the urlEncoded page.

Similarly, *On the Road* by Jack Kerouac generates a urlEncoded = [https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:"On+the+Road"+inauthor:"Jack+Kerouac"&country=CA](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:%22On+the+Road%22+inauthor:%22Jack+Kerouac%22&country=CA) and then returns an isbn = 9780142437254, also not found on the previous page (i.e., urlEncoded).

Why doesn't it pull the first ISBN from these pages, or even from these pages at all?

Edit: For Tchaikovsky's *Children of Time* I was expecting isbn = 9781447273318.
For Kerouac's *On the Road* I was expecting isbn = 9781101127575

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of them? For example, what values of ISBN do you want to retrieve from your both samples in your question?

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks for the reply. I've updated the question a bit with the expected isbns.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question.